# How to generate firebase registration token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to generate firebase registration token with new method but unable to generate this is my code below:

**MyFirebaseInstanceIdService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);

    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {

            String token = instanceIdResult.getToken();
            Log.d("Token",token);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
package="com.app.retrofitapp">

<dist:module dist:instant="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".Users"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"></action>
    </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

There is no token is showing in log cat with above method.Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Change    `<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"></action>` to   `<action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />` in manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just fcm token(not bother about notification) you only need below service in manifest with action INSTANCE_ID_EVENT...

```
<service android:name=".fcm.FireBaseInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And after this add the below code in your activity (onCreate will be good)

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Failed", task.getException());
                            return;
                        }

                        String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                        Log.i("FCM", "Current token=" + token);
                    }
                });
```

You will get your current token there. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly Log the token into your onNewToken method of FireBaseMessagingService class...

```
@Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.i("FCM", "FCMMessagingService token=" + s);
        //store it in prefrence
        ApplicationPreferences.setFcmToken(getApplicationContext(), s);
    }
```

No need to call...(this method is useful when you want token in other class/activity)

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {

            String token = instanceIdResult.getToken();
            Log.d("Token",token);
        }
    });
```

Confirm two services in manifest file

```
        <service android:name=".fcm.FireBaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".fcm.FireBaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: Nope still not getting token.

Comment: Why my activity is not extending FirebaseInstanceIdService.

Comment: Please add this code into manifest and run your app again.
`<service android:name=".fcm.FireBaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>`

Comment: I have changed it as u said but still not getting.

Comment: Please update your latest code of manifest in the question too.

Comment: Do not replace. Add this code in manifest. It should have two services.`<service android:name=".fcm.FireBaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".fcm.FireBaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>`

Comment: First remove your existing service block from manifest. and then add above code. pls

Comment: why my activity is not extending FirebaseInstanceIdService

Comment: Why to extend FirebaseInstanceIdService to activity....why you need that?? FCM works fine without it.

Comment: Look at my activity does it look good or is there any problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195035/discussion-between-naitik-soni-and-digvijay).

Answer (score 0):

In your case this is giving the token, try debugging on the real device.

```
 @Override
   public void onNewToken(String token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

   }
```

Comment: Activity is not extending using FirebaseInstanceidService

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your Application class or in launch activity.

Without initialising your firebase instance token will never get generated.

```
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: But app is not getting crashed. If you didn't initialize it then app will be crashed

Comment: Yes app is not crashing but still I have initialized firebase app in my launcher activity but no change.

Comment: Which fireabase sdk version are you using in your app?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override    
  public void onNewToken(String token) {   
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
    Note - here you get the firebase token everytime. and you can save firebase token into your app or with your server.
  }
```