# Firebase Token won't get registered in AppPreferences Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

The issue is im usign the new method to obtain the FirebaseToken.

```
override fun onNewToken(token: String?) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        token?.let {
            println("TOKEN OBTAINED OR REFRESHED: " + it)
            AppPreferences(applicationContext).put(AppPreferences.Key.firebase_token, it)
        }
    }
```

However when i send the AppPreferences to display the token it shows empty, but the issue is...

> MessagingService: Got new or refreshed FCM token:
>   dhXchSXlM0E:APA91bHEueN9713Q62GCkrFbARFNM16LqRyMEEGXXh

The MessagingService already receive the token but it won't enter in the onNewToken function.

Im using the most updated version of the firebase library.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
```

and my Manifest looks like this.

```
<service android:name=".Service.Firebase.FirebaseMessagingService"
                android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Please if anyone know what is the problem please tell me...

Comment: So from where this message(token) is getting printed??

Comment: The token is returned from the MessagingService(as is should be) however when i print the token from the  onNewToken() the value is empty.

Comment: onNewToken method from FirebaseMessagingService will be invoked...<1> first time when app is installed <2> when token is updated from their side only.

Comment: If you want your current token in activity...see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625061/how-to-generate-firebase-registration-token/56626273#56626273

Comment: So the only way is directly from an Activity, i can't obtain the token from the onNewToken?

Comment: It's the way to fetch when you want....and onNewToken() will be called on the first install any way.